Unable to find firebase_core in Android studio hedgehog
iam Working on Flutter (android studio hedgehog).
i dont know how to add dependencies and cant find any option of it.
i need to download/add "firebase_core"
i'll be glad to hear from you guys.
-saw tutorials , but they were using visual studio code
-saw forums but didnt find

If you want to add dependencies like 'firebase_core' Then you need to follow the below steps:

Open the pubspec.yaml file in your flutter project.

You need to add the dependencies like:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^3.3.0  # replace with the latest version.


After that run flutter pub get command in your terminal or you will get an option in pubspec.yaml file in android studio for pub get.



ok brother thank you, let me check it

Open terminal in android studio or vs code and run
flutter pub add firebase_core

It will automatically add "firebase_core" dependency in your project with right version.
Bonus: you can add multiple package in your project with right version by following command.
flutter pub add package1,package2,package3 

